# Default Document for IIS 7 not viewable

Tags: iis-7, default-document

On Windows 2008R2 I'm trying to set up my website so that it can be referenced as `http://xyz.com/`. It currently works when referenced as `http://xyz.com/default.html`.

I have added `Default.html` to the *Default Document* settings and I also checked the `web.config` to make sure it is there (see below).

I have Anonymous Authentication Enabled as a specific user.  I also have Windows Authentication Enabled.

My predecessor got everything working fine in II6 but I can't figure out what I'm missing in II7.

Comment: `c` tag removed. You don't want [pointers](http://boredzo.org/pointers/) (ha!) in answers, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the default doc handler was removed.  For example, if the httpHandler (Classic app pool) or handler (Integrated app pool) has a  then it could pull important handlers out, which need to be added back again.

If you go to c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config, search for defaultdoc and see the examples of what a default doc handler should look like.  Then add that back to your web.config file.  If it's not in apphost.config then you can install it using Server Manager and adding to the IIS role.

Comment: We tried this and also updated some settings on the ISAPI and CGI restrictions and now it is working.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @GISMapper Would you mind sharing what you did to make it work. I've a similar situation here, but couldn't figure it out.